# NOT NULL constraint failed: food_app_recipe.user_id in django

Tags: django

I am getting this error i don't know what's the issue. I am very beginner in django. The error here is
NOT NULL constraint failed: food_app_recipe.user_id when i trying to post data from template. Help with the error here

Here is my Models.py

```
from django.db import models

    # Create your models here.
    class User(models.Model):
        name = models.CharField(max_length=20,null=True)
        email = models.CharField(max_length=100,null=True)
        date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

        def __str__(self):
            return self.name

    class Recipe(models.Model):
        name = models.CharField(max_length=50,null=True)
        steps = models.TextField(max_length=1000,null=True)
        image = models.ImageField(null = True, blank = True)
        ingredients = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
        description = models.TextField(max_length=1000,null=True)
        user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

        def __str__(self):
            return self.name
```

Here is my forms.py

```
from django import forms
from django.forms import ModelForm
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from .models import Recipe

class SignupForm(UserCreationForm):
    username = forms.CharField(max_length=30)
    email = forms.EmailField(max_length=200)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username','email','password1','password2']

class RecipeForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Recipe
        fields = ['name','steps','image','ingredients','description']
```

Here is my Views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from .forms import SignupForm,RecipeForm
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate,login,logout
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.contrib import messages
from .models import User,Recipe

# views here

@login_required(login_url='blog-login')
def add_recipes(request):
    user = request.user
    form = RecipeForm(instance=user)
    if request.method == "POST":
        print('printing post:',request.POST)
        form = RecipeForm(request.POST,request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('blog-home')
    context = {'form':form}
    return render(request,'food_app/Add_recipe.html',context)
```

Here is my template of that form

```
{% block content %}

<div class = "container mt-4">
        <div class = "row justify-content-center">
            <div class = "col-6">
                <div class = "card">
                    <div class = "card-body">
                      <form action="" method="POST" class="form">
                {% csrf_token %}
                {% bootstrap_form form %}
                {% buttons %}
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                    Submit
                    </button>
                {% endbuttons %}

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>          

{% endblock content %}
```

Comment: I'm not sure but looks like you need to add `instance` to the `form = RecipeForm(request.POST,request.FILES)` line too.

Also, check that if you want to save a image, you need to use `<form action="" method="POST" class="form" enctype="multipart/form-data>` on template that form, or it will denied the files.

Answer (score 2):

When you are trying to save your `RecipeForm` django tries to create a new `Recipe`. Your model definition for `Recipe` contains a mandatory user field. However, your `RecipeForm` does not supply this information, i.e it has no user field. This is why you get the error.

In order to solve this you can add the the user before saving the recipe to the database. You do this by using `commit=False` when calling form.save():

```
form = RecipeForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
recipe = form.save(commit=False)
recipe.user = request.user
recipe.save()
```

One further remark: Your `RecipeForm` is a `ModelForm` for `Recipe`, passing `instance=request.user` does not make sense.

And @Tane comment regarding the enctype in your html form is correct